# Understanding the Exercise 9.9.5 of Weibel homological algebra

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, homological-algebra, kt.k-theory-and-homology, derham-cohomology

The exercise 9.9.5 of Weibel's homological algebra states that

$\textbf{Exercises 9.9.5}$ If $Z$ is a nilpotent ideal of $R$ and $k$ is a field of $char(k) = 0$, show that $H_{dR}^{\ast}(R) \cong H_{dR}^{\ast}(R/I)$.

where $R$ is commutative positively graded $k$-algebra. Here, I don't understand what is $Z$? He used the $Z(R)$ to denote the cyclic module associated to ring $R$, but which is nilpotent does not make sense. So what I am understanding is that this $Z$ should be $I$ in above exercise. But in that case exercise becomes:

$\textbf{Exercises}$ If $I$ is a nilpotent ideal of $R$ and $k$ is a field of $char(k) = 0$, show that $H_{dR}^{\ast}(R) \cong H_{dR}^{\ast}(R/I)$.

which looks very suspicious.   Even though this is true when we replace $H^{\ast}_{dR}$ by periodic cycle homology $HC^{per}_{\ast}$ but for de Rham cohomology it seems very odd. Can someone clear this confusion  whether this is typo error (Z instead of I) or the original exercise really mean something else.

Comment: There is a correction to the exercise listed here: https://sites.math.rutgers.edu/~weibel/Hbook.errors.edition2.pdf

Comment: Are you looking at the hardback version? My paperback copy of Weibel's Intro to HA says: if $I$ is a nilpotent ideal of $R$ and $k$ has characteristic zero, show that $H^*_{dR}(R)=H^*_{dr}(R/I)$

Comment: @ZhenLin Oops, I didn't notice that! Guess this shows that I didn't study this book as diligently as I should have during my PhD studies ...

Comment: Nor did I, but I remembered seeing comprehensive errata for this book. Lesson: check errata first!

Comment: @zhen  this correction says that this exercise is wrong and replace by some different exercise.

Comment: @Yemen Can you share the link of your version where it is written as in form of our new exercise.